# Automate button click function in Angular v11

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component file. Just need to automate the click event to get triggered once in a day or week

**HTML PAGE:**

```html
<button (click)="CreateTask()">Click It</button>
```

Having a button only.

**TS File:**

```
CreateTask() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.resultArray.length; i++) {
    this.contactsservice.PostClockifyContacts(this.resultArray[i]).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      }
    );
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.FilterTasks()
  }, 45000);
}
FilterTasks() {
  console.log("inside")
  this.contactsservice.PostClockifyFilter().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("Filter Request Successfully")
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Error", error);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Mock this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: I need to trigger button of my application once in a week or day. Above documentation still has an event of mouseover etc..

Comment: Syed, Use an inbuilt an inbuilt setinterval timer